# Simple example of recursive run through string characters in Erlang

Tags: recursion, erlang

I can't get how I can go through all characters in a string, can you please share a simple example?

I have a string, like

```
"function(){var a = 10; var b = 5; return a + b;}".
```

Now I want to "cycle" through the string character by character and do something depending on its value.

Here is my code which doesn't work, while running as `lexme("some string here").`:

```
lexme(S) ->
    lexme(S, 1).

lexme([H | T], _) ->
    io:fwrite("~p~n", [H]),
    T.
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? What result does it give? And what result do you want?

Comment: I want to do something with each character, one by one. Like, take "f", do something, then take "u", and do something, and so on.

Comment: Does the code you have write the first character?

Comment: Yes, it writes first character and ends there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make `lexme/2` recursive, it must call itself.

Try this:

```
lexme([H | T], _) ->
    io:fwrite("~p~n", [H]),
    lexme(T, 1).
```

I'm not sure what you intend to do with the second parameter. You're ignoring it, so why is it there?

You'll also want a function head that deals with the empty list so that the recursion can terminate, so the full definition would be something like this:

```
lexme([], _) ->
    done;
lexme([H | T], _) ->
    io:fwrite("~p~n", [H]),
    lexme(T, 1).
```

See http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion for more information.

Comment: I am new to Erlang, and the second parameter was intended to identify that function as a different one with different arity.